# Documentation on System.Deployment

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a Win Application which is publish using ClickOnce deployment (go though VS IDE). I want to develop another small application (Web) to do this deployment process without going though VS IDE. I heard about System.Deployment and Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine name spaces. But I count find good doc to solve my problem. If you have one please send me any references.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=system.deployment+assembly